the obligation of a male of 20
In the Old Testament, the Book of Numbers 1/3 20 year olds can be called up for military service. Now somewhere, there are also passages relating to the requirement to be met before one is 21 and secondly there is a punishment for those who refuse military service, but I cannot find either. Could you enlighten me please.

I cannot find any such texts.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is certainly clear in Numbers 1:3   (and verse 45) that the age at which young men were to start to be counted as called to do military service was 20 years. However, that was with regard to a census of all met fit for military service: "From 20 years old and upwards."
At the time of that particular census, there was no state of war going on. It was a preparatory measure, a logistical step, to know the potential for raising an army should a war happen around that time.
When king David ordered a census of fighting men in Israel, there was no mention of the starting age. (2 Samuel 24:2-4) Further, it was an illegal census, and God's judgment came, as a result.
I do not know of any Old Testament verses speaking of calling up men younger than 20 years of age, nor of punishment for refusing to engage in military service (at any age.) For this Hermeneutics site, questions are expected to show research done to try to get an answer first, before submitting the question. It is not meant to be a platform for just seeking others to provide biblical texts. So, if you could bear that in mind for your future questions, that would be good.
